# how do you grep certain parts of a string in R

Tags: regex, r

I have string like this:

```
x<-c("Total_Login.P00B.DC1")
```

or

```
x<-c("Total_Login..P00B.DC1")
```

I need to grep everthing after the fist dot (.) and replace any other special characters in the string with dash (-)

I tried something like this

```
gsub(".*\\.(.*)", "\\1",x)
```

but is is giving me DC1

I need my end results to be:

```
P00B-DC1
```

Comment: @akrun, no, I need everything after the first occurence of the dot.

Comment: Try `sub('.*\\.([^.]+)\\.(.*)$', '\\1-\\2', x)`

Comment: @akrun, it works on a single string but when I try to use it in a script for loop, it is giving me all kinds of problems.

Comment: My solution was based on the example you provided.  If you have other patterns, you should post that one.

Comment: @akrun, thank you. I just updated the post. What if there was . or ..

Comment: Try `sub('[^.]+\\.+([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)+$', '\\1-\\2', x)` where `x <- c("Total_Login.P00B.DC1", "Total_Login..P00B.DC1")`

Comment: The `*` operator is greedy, it takes as many characters as possible, which is everything until the LAST dot. Try starting your pattern with `.*?` instead.

Comment: If there are multiple instances of `.`, may be this helps `gsub('[.]', '-', sub('[^.]+\\.+', '', x))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would split on `.`, drop the first element and paste together:

```
paste0(strsplit(x,"\\.+")[[1]][-1],collapse="-")
# [1] "P00B-DC1"
```

And for a vector of strings (from @akrun's comment):

```
xvec      <- c("Total_Login.P00B.DC1", "Total_Login..P00B.DC1")

mycleaner <- function(x) paste0(strsplit(x,"\\.+")[[1]][-1],collapse="-")
sapply(xvec, mycleaner)
#  Total_Login.P00B.DC1 Total_Login..P00B.DC1 
#            "P00B-DC1"            "P00B-DC1"
```

The OP failed to define "special character", but this seems to work for the examples.

Comment: Plus, the OP could be wasting everyone's time by not providing more examples. Two matches with similar layouts provide little insight into what is needed.

Comment: @plafort I am guessing that in addition to the example showed, there will be multiple instances of `.` in the string and the `strsplit` is easier if that is the case.

Comment: I don't understand why anyone wouldn't provide 5 or 6 differing examples. But it's solved, so

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
x<-c("Total_Login.P00B.DC1", "Total_Login..P00B.DC1")
gsub('.*\\.+(.*\\..*)','\\1',x)
```

Comment: This will not give the expected answer.  Please check the OP's post.  Also, if there are multiple instances ` x<-c("Total_Login.P00B.DC1", "Total_Login..P00B.DC1", "Total_Login..POOB.DC1.DC2")`, it will fail

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
gsub('[.]', '-', sub('[^.]+\\.+', '', x))
#[1] "P00B-DC1"     "P00B-DC1"     "POOB-DC1-DC2"
```

#### data

```
x<-c("Total_Login.P00B.DC1", "Total_Login..P00B.DC1", 
           "Total_Login..POOB.DC1.DC2")
```